# SQL Query Grouped by Product, Count two variables in one Column

Tags: sql

I probably have a very simple problem that I can't solve. I want a SQL query that counts two values in a column and returns this value grouped by my products.

I have a table that looks like this

[this is the source table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQRJ1.png)

How can I make an evaluation in SQL which generates the following table:

[this is my target table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/88qom.png)

```
SELECT Product, Count(Role) as NumRole,
                        (SELECT Product, count(Role) as NumAdmin FROM tblprod WHERE Type='Admin') AS Admin,
                        (SELECT Product, count(Role) as NumAdmin FROM tblprod WHERE Type='User') AS User,
                        FROM tblprod
                        GROUP BY Product
```

Comment: Your language is not appropriate for a Q&A site.

Comment: please tag with database platform

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below query.

```
select product,
       sum(case when role='User' then 1 else 0 end) as Users,
       sum(case when role='Admin' then 1 else 0 end) as Admin
from tblprod
group by product
```